# Histogram of a label

Tags: r

I am a real beginner here so bear with me...

I've got

```
data <- c(XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX, ... in total 105 of these)
categories <- gl(5,21,105,labels=c('thing_A','thing_B','thing_C','thing_D','thing_E'))
```

I can plot a histogram of the data

```
hist(data)
```

Now I want to plot a histogram for the data in category thing_A. Of course, this code doesn't work but this is what I attempted

```
hist(data~categories[labels=="thing_A"])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `hist(data[categories=="thing_A",])`

Comment: Error in data[categories == "thing_A", ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: Actually data[categories == "thing_A"] worked (without the comma)! Thanks! Can you suggest it as an answer :)

Comment: oops, yes -- I misread `categories` as being a row of `data` (and my answer wouldn't have worked in that case anyway!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `data[categories == "thing_A"]`

and I would suggest Googling `"r subset data frames"` for more information ... or `?"["` within R, if you want a terse, technical summary ...